# Why does my script not activate when I run it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where my slow motion script is only activating when the player dies.Sometimes the script doesn't even work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SlowMotionText : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool slowMotionActive = false;

    public float speedFactor = .5f;

    public GameObject slowMotion;

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            slowMotionActive = !slowMotionActive;
        }
        if (slowMotionActive == true)
        {
            slowMotion.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = speedFactor;
            Debug.Log("true");
        }
        if (slowMotionActive == false)
        {
            slowMotion.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            Debug.Log("false");
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue what could have caused this to happen.

Comment: Your slowMotion gameObject is the same GameObject with this SlowMotionText script?

Comment: "Sometimes the script doesn't even work", could you explain more..? is this the script which causes problem or the way it is called?

Comment: @Frenchy , i fixed the part where it doesn't work, now I just need to figure out how to get it to work when the scene loads for the first time.

Comment: @QuentinCondie have you try fixed update when player die then call this script

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the project as a windows exe and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: Anyway you would want to execute the code in your `if` blocks only **once** when you press the key instead of every frame. Also Using `Debug.Log` frame-wise is pretty expensive and just slows down your app later

Comment: @derHugo - I'll remember to put those in a comment.